# Minitest data submission format for datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-coverage, minitest

A controller action parses an optional datetime collection select with
`if params[:individual]["birth_date_ui(1i)"].present?`

However when testing one cannot format the request as:

```
post individuals_url, params: { individual: { birth_date_ui(1i): 1990, birth_date_ui(2i): 12, [...] } }
```

as this does not appreciate handling the colon after parenthesis: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting => (SyntaxError)   ..., birth_date_ui(1i): 1990, birth_date_ui(2i): 12`

Yet providing a different syntax of parameters,

```
birth_date_ui: Date.today - 48.years
```

the above block of data is deemed not covered by the coverage gem.  It also submit a date string not a datetime sting.

How can the test be written to properly verify the presence and subsequent processing of datetime parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You may also create symbols by interpolation:
>
> ```rb
> :"my_symbol1"
> :"my_symbol#{1 + 1}"
> ```

*https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbol+Literals*

```rb
{ "birth_date_ui(1i)": 1990, "birth_date_ui(2i)": 12 }
```